# Count Male and female group by age in SQL Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in access with basic data of clients (name, DNI, DOB, Gender and Data date) and i want to count male and female grouping by age.

I can make the simple query:

```
SELECT Round((Date()-[DOB])/365.5) AS AGE, 
        Count(Datos.DNI) AS Count_Persons, 
        Datos.GENDER
 FROM Datos
      WHERE (Datos.GENDER= "M" OR Datos.GENDER="F") AND 
            Year([DATE_DATE])=Year(Date()) 
            AND DOB IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY Round((Date()-[DOB])/365.5), Datos.GENDER
      ORDER BY Datos.GENDER, Round((Date()-[DOB])/365.5);
```

showing the result with this format:

| Count_Persons | Age | GENDER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 95 | 25 | M |
| 120 | 25 | F |
| 15 | 26 | M |
| 52 | 27 | M |
| 35 | 27 | F |

But i want to show the data like this:

| Count_Male | Count_Female | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 95 | 120 | 25 |
| 15 | 0 | 26 |
| 52 | 35 | 27 |

I tried to use this query, but it doesn't work:

```
select
  Round((Date()-[DOB])/365.5) AS EDAD,
  count(IIF(GENDER="M", 1)) as MALE,
  count(IIF(GENDER="F", 1)) as FEMALE
from Datos
WHERE Year([DATA_DATE])=Year(Date()) AND DOB IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Round((Date()-[DOB])/365.5), Datos.GENDER
ORDER BY Datos.GENDER, Round((Date()-[DOB])/365.5);
```

This give me the result with a bunch of zeros:

| MALE | FEMALE | AGE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 95 | 0 | 25 |
| 15 | 0 | 26 |
| 52 | 0 | 27 |
| 0 | 120 | 25 |
| 0 | 35 | 27 |

¿How can I solve this problem?
Thanks you very much!

Comment: That would be a basic CROSSTAB query. Use the Access query designer or wizard.

Comment: Since you want Gender as column headers, do not include Gender in GROUP BY or ORDER BY.